# SQL: Select from table with variable

Tags: mysql, sql, database, prestashop

I've just recently started to delve into SQL so this is more than likely a simple syntax error but I'm stuck nonetheless. 
I've run this through a syntax checker (how much that helps, I'm not sure) and it's returning an error at line 6. I'm drawing a blank, so any direction at all would be much appreciated.

I'm trying to return "o" from a table once a row fulfils product_id=12 in order for me to find the next required piece of data

```
SELECT 
o.`id_order`,
cs.`id_customer`,
ord.`id_customer`,
concat( cs.`firstname`,' ', cs.`lastname`) as "Customer"

FROM `ps_order_detail` o (WHERE product_id=12)
join `ps_orders` ord on o.`id_order`=ord.`id_order`
join `ps_customer` cs on ord.`id_customer`=cs.`id_customer`
```

Comment: why 2 double quota for "Customer"?

Comment: @GoudaElalfy my bad, typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is misplaced and should only appear after all `JOIN`s are done, like so:

```
SELECT 
o.`id_order`,
cs.`id_customer`,
ord.`id_customer`,
concat( cs.`firstname`,' ', cs.`lastname`) as "Customer"

FROM `ps_order_detail` o
join `ps_orders` ord on o.`id_order`=ord.`id_order`
join `ps_customer` cs on ord.`id_customer`=cs.`id_customer`

WHERE o.product_id=12
```

It will have the same filtering effect you want.

Answer (score 1):

you should use where condition after join, also remove 2 double quota for Customer

```
SELECT 
o.`id_order`,
cs.`id_customer`,
ord.`id_customer`,
concat( cs.`firstname`,' ', cs.`lastname`) as Customer

FROM `ps_order_detail` o 
join `ps_orders` ord on o.`id_order`=ord.`id_order`
join `ps_customer` cs on ord.`id_customer`=cs.`id_customer`
WHERE o.product_id=12
```